# mongodb/rails "exception: can't find special index: 2d for:"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, indexing, 2d

i have a rails app where i have some problems with indexes. I search locations by name.
First i thought its a problem with the addresses.coords but iam not sure about it.

The relevant parts of the search controller:

```
  @practices = Practice.published
  @practices = @practices.where(:"addresses.country" => params[:country].upcase) if  params[:country].present?

  if params[:location].present? && latlng = get_coordinates
    @practices = @practices.near_sphere(:"addresses.coords" => latlng).max_distance(:"addresses.coords" => get_distance )
  end

  # now find doctors based on resulting practices
  @doctors = Doctor.published.in("organization_relations.practice_id" => @practices.distinct(:_id))
```

The complete crash log:

```
Moped::Errors::OperationFailure (The operation: #<Moped::Protocol::Command
  @length=255
  @request_id=646
  @response_to=0
  @op_code=2004
  @flags=[]
  @full_collection_name="um-contacts.$cmd"
  @skip=0
  @limit=-1
  @selector={:distinct=>"practices", :key=>"_id", :query=>{"deleted_at"=>nil,     "published_at"=>{"$lte"=>2012-11-05 15:17:14 UTC}, "addresses.country"=>"DE", "addresses.coords"=>{"$nearSphere"=>[13.4060912, 52.519171], "$maxDistance"=>0.01569612305760477}}}
  @fields=nil>
failed with error 13038: "exception: can't find special index: 2d for: { deleted_at: null, published_at: { $lte: new Date(1352128634313) }, addresses.country: \"DE\", addresses.coords: { $nearSphere: [ 13.4060912, 52.519171 ], $maxDistance: 0.01569612305760477 } }"

See https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/docs/errors.md
for details about this error.):
  app/controllers/search_controller.rb:16:in `index'
```

Thats the result of the indexes, not sure how to query them from the addresses which are embedded via has_many.

```
> db.practices.getIndexes()

[

    {
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "um-contacts.practices",
    "name" : "_id_"
}

]
```

Help would be really appreciated!

Edit: Looks like the indexes for adresses.coords arent created,

```
db.system.indexes.find()
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "ns" : "um-contacts.users", "name" : "_id_" }
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "ns" : "um-contacts.doctors", "name" : "_id_" }
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "ns" : "um-contacts.collaborations", "name" : "_i
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "ns" : "um-contacts.practices", "name" : "_id_" }
```

but should be created within the practice class:

```
class Practice
 ...
 embeds_many :addresses, cascade_callbacks: true, as: :addressable
 ...
 field :name, type: String
 field :kind, type: String
 field :slug, type: String

 index({"addresses.coords" => '2d'}, { min: -180, max: 180, background: true })
 index({name: 1})
 index({slug: 1}, { unique: true })
 ...
```

Anyone have an idea why its failing?

Comment: Have you tried running db.practices.ensureIndex({addresses.coords : "2d"}) ?

Comment: db.practices.ensureIndex({"addresses.coords" : "2d"}) creates the Indexes and the error is gone, but shouldnt it be done by the code above?

Answer (score 0):

try to re-create your indexes. for mongoid:

```
rake db:mongoid:create_indexes
```